Weird characters always shown when opening a file
When I open new file using vim (Open file using vi also has the same problem), this always shows.

Or if the file has content, those characters will auto-replace the file content in place.
Environment: Centos-7
$TERM variable value is xterm-256color
I searched on Google, but answers like
https://superuser.com/questions/1336947/weird-characters-appearing-in-the-console
and others such as reset command
doesn't help in my case at all.
Any help is appreciated!
vim --clean gives me, still the characters


What happens if you use vim --clean (or if your Vim doesn't have --clean, then vim --Nu NONE)?

@muru Thx for the help, I screenshot the vim --clean interface into the question.
vim --Nu NONE gives me
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compiled Aug 23 2024 23:20:19)
Unknown option argument: "--Nu"
More info with: "vim -h"

Ah, that should be -Nu NONE, just one -, sorry

@muru no worries, vim -Nu NONE gives me the same output I linked in the post

Looks like a VT10x/ANSI style terminal control sequence of five characters.  Escape (0x1b) [ ? 4 m.  If your terminal program were configured to match the terminal type that vim expects, your terminal program would respond to the control sequence and not show it to you.  Which terminal is your terminal program emulating, and which terminal is your Linux configured to expect?  (heck, what Linux/Unix do you even have?)

@SottoVoce Yeah, I am on Centos7, and even I cat a.txt a file, those characters still shown at the beginning.
What you mean by which terminal is my terminal program emulating? How do I check this?

The question would be what terminal emulator software (gnome-terminal, putty, xterm, konsole...) are you using, and what terminal is it configured to emulate if any (check in its settings). vim will use $TERM (please show the value of that variable) to figure out what terminal you're using and can also send special escape sequences to identify the terminal further. Here it looks like it has the wrong guess. A terminal that would show that 001b for a \e[?4m sequence would also be very unusual.

@StéphaneChazelas $TERM gives xterm-256color

FWIW, \e[?4m is the escape sequence to query the state of the modifyOtherKeys key modifier option in xterm and is xterm-specific, terminals that don't support a given \e[...<letter> should however ignore that. So looks like a buggy terminal especially if it claims to emulate a 256 color xterm.

@StéphaneChazelas Thx for the info! But how do I resolve this? I tried reboot the VM or the whole laptop, but still with the same issue.
Is there a way to disable those modifyOtherKeys option? Or reset to default setting? Since this problem suddenly happens few days ago while I am not upgrading anything.

You'll likely need to start vim with a $TERM value that more closely matches your actual terminal software, but until you tell us which it is, we likely won't be able to help.

@StéphaneChazelas How do I check the terminal software? This is on my company mac -> Parallel Desktop 18 -> Centos 7, any idea on how to check the actual terminal software? I am not too familiar with linux, just know how to use it. Thx!

It looks like VTE-based gnome-terminal. If that's running on the VM (with a 10-year old and end-of-life operating system) itself and you're not sshing into the VM using a terminal on the host, it might still be affected by bugs such as https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403130

If that system has a gnome-256color terminfo entry (check if infocmp gnome-256color returns anything), running export TERM=gnome-256color would likely help.

@StéphaneChazelas Thx a lot! Yeah, it works now after your solution!

How come you have vim 9.1.646 (from July 2024) on a CentOS 7 VM (from 2014, meant to have vim 7.4.x)? That sending of \e[?4m on xterm was added to vim in  9.0.980 released in December 2022.

TERM=vte-256color may be preferable (gnome-256color is now deprecated; though I don't know what the situation was in that regard in 2014).

That's an old bug of VTE, the terminal emulation component used by several terminal emulators including GNOME Terminal which appears to be the one you're using.
VTE used to display the characters in (some of) the control sequences it didn't recognise instead of ignoring them.
Here you see a 001b in a box which is meant to be a visual representation of the ESC (aka \e or ^[ or U+001B) control character, followed by [ (\e[ being CSI, Control Sequence Introducer), ?, 4 and m.
As Thomas Dickey (the maintainer of ncurses, xterm and the terminfo database among other things) puts it:

It's a VTE bug.  Whether gnome-terminal, etc., do anything useful with
the escape sequence is irrelevant since it is a well-formed control
sequence (so VTE has to be able to parse it, not get confused and let
haracters echo onto the screen).  Echoing the sequence is incorrect.

Here \e[?4m is the escape sequence to query the state of the modifyOtherKeys key modifier option in xterm, added to xterm in version 377 in 2022, so long after CentOS 7 was released. So the vim that comes with CentOS 7 would never have sent it.
However, you're using a version of vim from 2024, much newer than the 7.4 one that comes with (the now end-of-life) CentOS 7 from 2014.
vim started sending that sequence when run on terminals claiming to be xterm in 9.0.0980 from December 2022.
modifyOtherKeys (itself added in version 214 in 2006) is to enable an input mode where upon key presses, xterm sends an escape sequence that encodes which key was pressed along with the list of modifiers (such as shift, ctrl, alt, numlock...) so an interactive application such as vim can bind those to some action.
Here, $TERM is set (by gnome-terminal) to xterm-256color. That means it claims to be a terminal emulator compatible with xterm¹. vim only sends that \e[?4m when it thinks the host terminal is xterm-compatible. I've not looked at the code, but it appears it's linked to whether $TERM contains xterm, so to avoid it sending that sequence which triggers that VTE bug, you'd need to use a $TERM value compatible with the VTE terminal emulation that does not contain xterm.
Looking at the list of terminfo entries shipped with CentOS 7 in http://buildlogs.cdn.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64-latest/Packages/ncurses-term-5.9-13.20130511.el7.noarch.rpm, these two:



$TERM value
Description




gnome-2012
GNOME Terminal 3.6.0


vte-2012
VTE 0.34.1



(as reported by toe on the extracted terminfo directory) look like they would be close matches for the GNOME Terminal emulator you're using, closer matches than xterm-256color (see infocmp -L vte-2012 xterm-256color for the differences; vte-2012 and gnome-2012 are actually identical), except for the fact they claim VTE only supports up to 8 colours (while VTE has had 256 colour support since 0.20.2 in 2006) and happen not to contain xterm, so vim won't send that \e[?4m sequence which VTE not only doesn't support but also ends up incorrectly echoing.
Newer versions of the terminfo database that comes with ncurses have a vte-256color (VTE with xterm 256-colors, currently based on VTE 0.51.2) entry but that one doesn't seem to be present in the 10 year old one found in CentOS 7.
TL;DR
run:
export TERM=vte-2012

To work around the problem. Then vim will not send that escape sequence and not hit that bug in your old version of the VTE library used by your old GNOME Terminal. That also describes your terminal to vim better than xterm-256color, except (at least) for the number of supported colours. If you find that you're missing on the number of colours, you could try using a $TERM value for some other xterm-like terminal with 256 colour support as found in your old terminfo database such as mrxvt-256color (not the same as VTE either but possibly close enough for what vim does with it).

¹ which it is not really, but using a more specific value runs the risk of things breaking when for instance sshing into a system that has a limited set of terminfo/termcap entries. xterm-256color is common enough and close enough for most purposes.

Or alias vim to TERM=vte-2012 vim if it's only Vim that is affected.

(Mostly former) GNOME Terminal and VTE co-developer here.
While Stéphane's answer accurately covers a lot of technical details, I disagree with his final conclusion.
TERM values other than GNOME Terminal's (VTE's) default aren't tested by the software's developers, and are only tested by a tiny user base. Should you encounter any new problem, you are pretty much on your own. Maybe that workaround will work properly for you, maybe it won't, I honestly can't tell.
The said bug was fixed in VTE version 0.54 (which had a complete rewrite of its parser), released in Sep 2018, i.e. 6 years ago. You pair it up with a Vim version as of mid-this-year (mid-2024).
I generally consider it a bad idea to pair up software with this much gap. I mean, you surely don't browse the newest coolest homepages with a browser of 6 years ago, do you? Vim as of 6 years ago pretty certainly did not trigger this bug in VTE, we would have sooner implemented a quick one-off fix then. I'm almost sure Vim added whichever feature that triggers this bug noticeably later, by which time most people had already had a new enough VTE for this not to cause a problem (edit: I missed that Stéphane looked up the exact date: Vim started to use this escape sequence less than 2 years ago).

Update: the next two paragraphs are outdated: My suggestion is to update your VTE (package libvte2.91 or vte2.91 or similar) to 0.54 or newer. Generally the newer the better, although the newer the more likely your system is too old to compile it. You don't need to update GNOME Terminal itself, that's only the UI around VTE. Once you install a newer VTE and quit all your GNOME Terminal windows at once, the newly started GNOME Terminal will use the new VTE. Verify by executing echo $VTE_VERSION.
I highly recommend to install an independent, i.e. non-VTE-based terminal emulator beforehand, so that if you mess up the installation and GNOME Terminal doesn't start up then you can fix the situation (at least revert to the old version) without having to switch away from the graphical desktop to the Linux VT (console).
Update: Forget the previous two paragraphs. I've just realized your system ships a very old VTE, namely version 0.34.6, which is 11+ years old. Subsequently, 0.36 brought an API change, so you cannot simply upgrade. There have been countless amount of improvements and fixes in VTE since then. No one should still be using that ancient version.

As I already said, I generally find it a bad idea to have such a big difference between the ages of software components; in this very example a difference of 11 years. If, for whatever reason, you need to or prefer to have a crispy new Vim, in my opinion your base system should be reasonably closely up-to-date too. Speaking of which...
The CentOS homepage tells me that CentOS 7 has reached its end of life 3 months ago. That is, if I'm not mistaken, you will no longer
receive any security updates. Independently of the current VTE + Vim problem, you should upgrade your entire system ASAP. Doing so will almost certainly give you a new enough VTE and thereby automatically eliminate this problem.
You should not be looking for workarounds, such as alternate TERM values. You should upgrade your entire system in the very-very near future. (Or: should you be happy with a 10-11 year old base system that no longer receives security fixes, my 2 cents is that you should also be happy with a Vim from several years ago.)

The vte-2012 terminfo entry back in 2014 was intended to describe the capabilities of the VTE emulator from the era. xterm-256color is that for xterm. It looks like that terminfo entry is not (and wasn't back then) fully accurate, but VTE doesn't fully emulate xterm either (even if we consider only the capabilities covered by terminfo). Looking at infocmp -xL vte-256color xterm-256color with the latest version of ncurses, there are many differences. (continued in next comment).

(continued) IMO, if the intention is for VTE to fully emulate xterm (or at least enough for the xterm-256color entry to correctly reflect its capabilities), VTE developers should cooperate with those of ncurses to address all those differences: fixing the parts where the terminfo entry is incorrect (like possibly the number of colours or the cvvis capability which AFAICT VTE supports) and where VTE must be updated to match the xterm behaviour. Even then using xterm-256color may not be desirable as there are features present in VTE not present in xterm. (continued in next comment)

(continued) For instance, with TERM=xterm-256color, tput Smulx 2 to enable double-underline doesn't work even though VTE has the capability.

@StéphaneChazelas Thank you for your comments! We've drifted quite far away from the original question. As for what VTE should do wrt. terminfo, would you be okay with continuing this conversation in private email? I'd be happy to.

My comments were in response do your "disagreement to my final conclusion". Feel free to follow up in email, but note that I don't have a strong interest in the specific matters as I'm not a regular user of any VTE-based terminal.
